# Get the unique values of column in dataframe on the other column condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
id  name        count
123 ssdf        1
123 wasdfasdf   1
234 ewdd        0
345 efdfg       2
345 efg         1
345 gfdfg       1
456 gfdfg       1
456 ffg         1
567 vd          3
```

Here there is id and count columns, how many id's are there where count is 1. 
If one id has 1,1,1 then i need that id in the result list. 
if the id has 0,1,1 then never mind. 
if the id has 0,3,0 then never mind.

Expected result:

```
list_1 = ['123','456']
```

also can i please expect the answer as the function in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['count'].transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & (x == 1)), 'id'].unique()
```

Output:

```
array([123, 456])
```

Using transform to label each record if it belongs to an 'id' with only one count and that count is equal to 1.  Then, use boolean index filtering and column selection to get only those values and use unique to generate a list of unique ids.

### As a function...

```
def unique_list_ids(df, valuecount):
    resultlist = (df.loc[df.groupby('id')['count']
                           .transform(lambda x: (x.nunique() == 1) & 
                                                (x == valuecount)), 
                         'id'].unique())
    return resultlist

unique_list_ids(df, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([123, 456])
```

Comment: can i please get the answer as the python function

Comment: @kanna What are your inputs?  Dataframe and the value of count?

Comment: awesome, i will try now. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a solution that is relatively slow but easy to understand.

```
target1 = df.query("count == 1").id.unique() # possible candidates
target2 = df.query("count != 1").id.unique() # candidates wish to exclude

list_1 = []

for i in target1:
    if i not in target2:
        list_1.append(i)

print(list_1)
```

OutPut:

```
['123', '456']
```